# Is there an efficient algorithm to organize a graph of connected points to minimize the distance between the connection points?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, gpu, graph-theory, gpgpu

I have a graph of 10 million nodes connected to roughly 120 other nodes each. I am hoping to visualize all these nodes and their interactions in an easy and intuitive way.

Is there a way to give every node an x and y coordinate to minimize the distance to each of the nodes it is connected to?

Currently, I have which partition each node resides in, in an 8x8x8 space. I also, for each node, have a list of each of the forward connections. Each node can connect to any other node within ±1 partition.

I'm hoping I can find a parallelizable algorithm to run this in real-time at 20hz.

Thanks for any input anyone has!

I honestly haven't tried anything yet, I can't think of a single way to make this work. It's also likely that if I did find an algorithm to make this work, the way my graph is setup, it will just look like noise anyways.

Given that I have a partition location for each node, I thought about just laying all the neurons in a 2D array, but then I wouldn't get a clean visualization for the inter-partition connections.

I'm thinking that this is impossible to do in a reasonable amount of time. I'm asking this question here as a last resort.

Edit: I guess a trivial solution is to set all the coordinates to the same point. My intent is to map each node to a pixel, so every coordinate should be unique among the nodes.

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D?  You talk about x,y but no z, then you talk about 8 by 8 by 8 partitions

Comment: How many partitions do you have?  8 cubed, or somethin else?

Comment: Combine all the nodes in each partition into a single node with a "color" representing the number of combined nodes.  Forget about the connections between nodes in the same partition.  Display the combined nodes and the connections with nodes in other partitions.

Comment: AFAIK, there are several research on this topic. Many methods are iterative physics-based one. The convergence can be quite slow but showing iteration in real time should be possible on a good GPU with 10M nodes and a degree of 120. I advise to take a look at the state of the art first.

Comment: @ravenspoint I have 8 cubed partitions. Each node is stored, internally, in 3D space without coordinates by their partition number. I want to display them all in 2D space with unique coordinates.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks! I'm fairly new to this, I thought it might have some relation to parallel collision detection, but other than that I don't know any of the research terms. Would you be willing to provide me any terms that I could use to Google? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You have 10 million nodes that you want to display separately in 2D?  You will need a screen with a resolution of more than 3,000 by 3,000  pixels.  This is not practical.

Comment: @ravenspoint I have a 4K display, Once I can figure out this algorithm, I'll figure out a way to reduce nodes. I'll most likely reduce the nodes 4:1 down to 2.5 million. That way I don't need to force the entire image into a fixed aspect ratio. Also, the node count is not static, I can adjust it as I like. I just figured these details were out of scope of the question so I didn't mention them.

If needed, I could buy 2 more 4K monitors and put them in a 2x2 configuration, but I doubt that will be necessary.

Comment: scholar.google.com is the way to go for research papers, not the usual search engine. I expect GraphViz (for small graphs) and Gephi (for large graphs) to provide links to research papers. I use Gephi for years. It is a bit slow but not well optimized and AFAIK written in Java but it scale well. They provide a [simple short paper](https://gephi.org/publications/gephi-bastian-feb09.pdf) on their website that may contain interesting links (in the reference section).

Comment: Alternatively, a quick search results in [Visualization of Large Graphs Using GPU Computing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6630509) which seems a good starting point ;) (DOI: 10.1109/INCoS.2013.126).